# Transit / Duration Errors in d3js and Meteor

Tags: d3.js, meteor

I've been looking for a solution for this but no luck. I can't get rid of this error, yet every example for d3 in Meteor that I've seen has it.

**Array Getting Passed to d3:**

- {categoryName:"Shooter", count:"19"}
- {categoryName:"Action",
  count:"23"}

**Error Encountered in Console:**

- "TypeError: slice.transition is not a function"
- "TypeError: slice.duration is not a function"

**Guide I've Been Following:**
http://bl.ocks.org/dbuezas/9306799

**Code:**
https://gist.github.com/mayvn10/83d062eb7fd257b07c33

If anyone can shed some light on why transition and duration don't work, I'm all ears!

Thanks!

Comment: How do you load the d3 library into your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the enter like this...

```
var slice = svg.select(".slices")
                    .selectAll("path")
                    .data(pie(resultArray), function(d) { return d.data.categoryName; });

        slice.enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("class", "slice")
            .attr("d", arc)
            .attr("fill", function(d) {
                return color(d.data.categoryName);
            });
```

The `enter` object has reduced functionality, it doesn't have a `.transition` property for example.  The object returned by `.data()` is a normal selection object and has all `selection.prototype` methods, including transition.

Comment: that worked, thank you!

can you explain why the enter had to be moved this way?

Comment: Cool Blue, now that it's working, the labels are all too close to each other.

Do you have a good approach on how to add some top and bottom padding to the labels?

I tried .style("padding", "5px 0"); but it wasn't working even though it was adding the inline-style.